# uri para file provider

Tags: java, android-studio

tengo un problema al generar el uri para un archivo adjunto para gmail, el código que tengo es el siguiente.

```
introducir el código aquí

((Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonSendFeedback)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListe`n`er() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String to = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtTo)).getText().toString();
                String sub = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtSubject)).getText().toString();
                String cc = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.ccto)).getText().toString();

                Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.example.pruebarsinuevo", new File("sample.pdf"));

                Intent mail = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                mail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{to});
                mail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, new String[]{cc , "ordendeservicio_rsi@outlook.com, rigo0708alejo@gmail.com"});
                mail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, sub);
                mail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "orden de servicio" );
                mail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
                mail.setType("message/rfc822");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(mail, "Enviar email por:"));

            }
        });
```

y el error que me marca es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

no se como seria la forma correcta para colocar esta uri para file provider y que funcione correctamente de antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

El error:

> getUriForFile() in 'androidx.core.content.FileProvider' cannot be
> applied to '(anonymous android.view.View.OnClickListener

ocurre en esta linea de código:

```
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.example.pruebarsinuevo", new File("sample.pdf"));
```

**el problema es el contexto que usas, en este caso no debes usar this, usa `v.getContext()` o `getApplicationContext()`** :

```
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), "com.example.pruebarsinuevo", new File("sample.pdf"));
```